# how do I pass a byte[] reference as the buffer in a System.Net.Sockets.Send().Recieve()

Tags: c#, sockets, memory-management

I have been reading about the various memory management issues that .NET Asynchronous Sockets have.

There are but a handful of links, but spidering this one will get you them all:
http://codebetter.com/blogs/gregyoung/archive/2007/06/18/async-sockets-and-buffer-management.aspx

**Basically**
when a socket is asynchronously sending/receiving many small byte[]'s
the send/receive byte[]'s are pinned in memory
leading to fragmentation.

SO for the purposes of creating a buffer manager :
I have a managed buffer (byte[])

```
byte[] managedBuffer = new byte[1024];
// do stuff with managedBuffer;
```

how do I send this byte[] to the socket's asynchronous .BeginSend() method by reference?

```
// I don't want to pass the VALUE to the method, but a reference
// to managedBuffer;
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(managedBuffer...(other params));
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the memory management issues you're referring to?

Comment: @Jon B - Done - Enjoy - It has opened up a new world for me!

Comment: @divinci - Interesting read. It looks like he's recommending ArraySegment instead of a regular array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by Nik, you are already passing it by reference when you pass the `byte[]` to the method. However, there are benefits to using the `ArraySegment` method you found in the documentation; they are primarily to avoid memory fragmentation issues inherent in the pinning of the `byte[]` buffer during an async call.

See my answer to: [How to write a scalable Tcp/Ip based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869744/how-to-write-a-scalable-tcp-ip-based-server/908766#908766) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are always passed by reference, so you're already doing that.  If you're using the socket asynchronously then you'll need to make sure you don't use managedBuffer while it's in progress.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are always passed as a reference (like passing a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that BeginSend does with the byte data is sending it over to the opened Socket. After that the byte array would get disposed (at the end of the function, or when the class where the array is defined gets disposed) like any other byte array in .NET by the GC.