# How to handle external types with protobuf-net precompile tool?

Tags: protobuf-net

I am trying to use protobuf-net precompile tool from the latest release (r622) and I was wondering how to handle types that I can't decorate with ProtoContract attributes.

More specifically, when the precompile tool process custom types aggregating XNA members (Vector3, Matrix, etc...) I get the following expected error:

`No serializer defined for type: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3`

Since I can't add attributes to those types, what is the recommended way to deal with this ? Should I revert back to the old way of having my own precompile tool creating and compiling a custom TypeModel ?

Comment: Excellent question, and I'm open to suggestions. In particular, when compiling *properly* for cross-platform, I'm only opening the assemblies for *inspection*, so I can't use runnable code (a static method etc) in the assembly. I'm wondering whether doing something like a script-based file (iron python or lua or something), or whether to just use some kind of basic config file (JSON for example).

Comment: @MarcGravell Having some sort of config file is something that first came to mind as well. All you should need is the fully qualified type name and a list of strings to explicitly declare all the fields.
The problem i can see with this is that it might only be a temporary workaround for simple types.  
Instead of having an executable that has to deal with every single platform, why not simply provide a simplified API that we can use in our own serialization assembly generation tool

Comment: @Phillippe well, RuntimeTypeModel / MetaType is exactly that API at the current time. But I could simplify some of the IKVM loader code, perhaps. Writing your own compiler against the IKVM build (for full cross-target compile) is not as easy as it could be.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the info ! I decided to go the route of  [proxy types and implicit operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8901287/1886241) to make the conversion easy.