# Send and receive Hex String from linux Server C#

Tags: c#, linux, tcp, hex

I'm developing an developing a little software in c# that connect to a Linux server. the software send a HEX String and receive a HEX String Back.
 here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();

        tcpclient.Connect("192.168.0.100",9010);

        string msg = Console.ReadLine();

        Stream stream = tcpclient.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] enviar = ascii.GetBytes(msg);
        stream.Write(enviar, 0, enviar.Length);
        byte[] bit = new byte[255];
        int i = stream.Read(bit, 0,255);
        for (int a = 0; a < i; a++ ) {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(bit[0]));
        }
        tcpclient.Close();


    }
```

an example of a string is `0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x34 0x03 0x30 0x30 0x30` and the response is this `30 30 30 30 30 30 33 33 60 60 60 60 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF 01`

the deal is that a need to send a string to the server but don't get response, need to have a response like this

[realterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkTlT.jpg)

can you give a hand with the code please ?

Comment: You're not writing a hex string, you're writing a byte array. If you want to write a hex string like you say, you need to do something like `string.Join(" ", enviar.Select(b => string.Format("0x{0:X2}", b)));` That being said, writing a byte array makes way more sense to me from an efficiency standpoint than writing a hex string like you describe.

Comment: Back up a bit. You need a message plan. See this [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028242/2226988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure a) if it's a typo, and b) how you are determining you didn't get a reply

That said:
IF you are saying it by the console output, examine this line:

Console.Write(Convert.ToString(bit[**0**]));

I believe it should be:
Console.Write(Convert.ToString(bit[**a**]));

(also - naming a byte "bit" is a bit misleading - no pun intended)