# Video Streaming from Smartphone (Unity 3d) to PC with Unity3D

Tags: android, sockets, unity-game-engine

everyone.

I would like to stream the image from a cellphone camera to a PC using Unity3D. I know this question has been addressed but I found just [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717713/unity-live-video-streaming) solution using unity3d and part of the script is deprecated.

Does anyone know a tutorial or any thing that I could guide myself to start?

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any help

Comment: *"but I found just one solution using unity3d and part of the script is deprecated"* No part of that answer is deprecated. You will likely not find tutorials for such thing. Read image from the camera and send through network.  You must understand TCP socket + Threading and Unity coroutine in order to do that.

Comment: Hi @Programmer, I think the solution is yours. The part of the answers which is deprecated is the thread one. The library Loom is deprecated and I couldnt find a download for it on Asset Store.

Comment: I replaced these parts of the code with native Systems.Threading. I tried to run it, I didnt get any errors but it is not actually working. I created two projects, one to run on the cellphone (server) and the other one on my desktop (client) to receive the image camera's cellphone. This IP variable in the Receiver script is the ip address of the cellphone, right? Because, when I run the project, the console only shows the log warning "Connecting to server...", but nothing else.

Comment: You can find the `Loom` API on github by simply Googling `Loom.RunAsync`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found it on github indeed and the scripts worked perfectly.