# Unity Send huge file over Networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I try to send a picture weight some mb over Networking (UNet) API of Unity.
If try [ClientRpc] call, but it complain about the size of the packet... of course.
I know I could use WWW to send this file, but think it is not possible to receive such packet over Lan Networking. It is ?

Do you know what is there is a proper way to send huge file ? Or do I reeealy have to manually split into many many packet ?

Thanks

Comment: With UNet, you have to split the file then send. If you don't want to do this the use raw socket to send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a UNet splitter to send my photo using UNet (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1113376/unet-send-big-amount-of-data-over-network-how-to-s.html) but it take about 10s to send a picture ~1mb...

I also make another Socket connection using .Net. File sharing is almost instant, but you have to manage another connect/disconnect networking which is source of error and bugs and warning and pain ([Unity: Live Video Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717713/unity-live-video-streaming))

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to send a reference (like a name as a string) of that file, not the entire file. that means that every client needs access to that file.

Comment: I cannot, it is a screenshot the server (pc) made and have to send right away to one client

Comment: or else, I should run an apache server and share url to make a www request over file sharing... which make the deployment harder