# Transfering large data (>100 MB) over Mirror in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

`string SerializedFileString` contains a serialized file, potentially hundreds of MB in size. The server tries to copy it into the client's local `string ClientSideSerializedFileString`. Too good to be true, which is why it throws an exception. Is there a Mirror-way to do this?

```
[TargetRpc]
private void TargetSendFile(NetworkConnection target, string SerializedFileString)
{
    if (!hasAuthority) { return; }
    ClientSideSerializedFileString = SerializedFileString;
}
```

`ArgumentException The output byte buffer is too small to contain the encoded data, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallback'.`

Comment: Split into chunks I suppose...

Comment: Possible, but then the sequential arrival can't be guaranteed without further code around that.

Comment: I guess then you need the required code around it ;) split into packages, number them, wait until all are received in correct order .. eventually request lost packages again ... though that's basically the TCP protocol ;)

Comment: Probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157832/unity-send-huge-file-over-networking

Comment: I checked that. It seems like using Mirror is very slow in that regard. Others also suggest using TCP directly.