# Image Processing in Python from Unity Hololens Development

Tags: python, image, sockets, unity-game-engine, hololens

So I have an image processing algorithm doing crack detection written in Python and I want to have this work on the Hololens (in Unity). I don't have any experience with sockets, but I assume I would write a TCP server in Python and then Unity would be the client. Unity would send the captured image to the python server on the computer, the computer would do the heavy processing and just return the processed image frame to the Hololens (in Unity). If anyone has experience with this or can guide me in anyway in starting this I would greatly appreciate any help. Does my idea sound plausible?

Comment: It makes sense. You can start by googling "Hololens tcp tutorial". There should be many examples out there.

Comment: There aren't any examples of sending over images through tcp...

Comment: If you can send byte array, you can do it. You can convert the texture to png/jpg bye array then send it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717713/unity-live-video-streaming/42727918#42727918) is an example for server an client in Unity. It sends camera texture to another Unity app with tcp.