# Unity: Live Video Streaming ARCore Camera Texture

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, streaming, arcore

I'm trying to use TCP sockets to stream the texture from the ARCore camera on one device to the background image on another device. I've found some great resources that have got me close. This question helped me a lot: [Unity: Live Video Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717713/unity-live-video-streaming)

The only difference is that this example uses a WebcamTexture, which I've got working without any lag and smoothly.

However, obtaining the camera texture from ARCore is a bit of a different process. I think I'm doing this correctly but maybe I'm missing something. When I run this with the ARCore camera texture and my minor changes, the server lags significantly.

Below is my code. I made no changes to the client side code so I know it has to do with my server side changes.

SERVER:

```
public class MySocketServer : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    public RawImage myImage;
    public bool enableLog = false;

    Texture2D currentTexture;

    private TcpListener listner;
    private const int port = 8010;
    private bool stop = false;

    private List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();

    //This must be the-same with SEND_COUNT on the client
    const int SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT = 15;

    private void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        //Start WebCam coroutine
        StartCoroutine(initAndWaitForWebCamTexture());
    }


    //Converts the data size to byte array and put result to the fullBytes array
    void byteLengthToFrameByteArray(int byteLength, byte[] fullBytes)
    {
        //Clear old data
        Array.Clear(fullBytes, 0, fullBytes.Length);
        //Convert int to bytes
        byte[] bytesToSendCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteLength);
        //Copy result to fullBytes
        bytesToSendCount.CopyTo(fullBytes, 0);
    }

    //Converts the byte array to the data size and returns the result
    int frameByteArrayToByteLength(byte[] frameBytesLength)
    {
        int byteLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(frameBytesLength, 0);
        return byteLength;
    }

    IEnumerator initAndWaitForWebCamTexture()
    {
        // Open the Camera on the desired device, in my case IPAD pro
        //webCam = new WebCamTexture();
        // Get all devices , front and back camera
        //webCam.deviceName = WebCamTexture.devices[WebCamTexture.devices.Length - 1].name;

        // request the lowest width and heigh possible
        //webCam.requestedHeight = 10;
        //webCam.requestedWidth = 10;

        //myImage.texture = webCam;

        //webCam.Play();
        //currentTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24,false);  
        //currentTexture = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);

        // Connect to the server
        listner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

        listner.Start();

        while (Screen.width < 100)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //Start sending coroutine
        StartCoroutine(senderCOR());
    }

    WaitForEndOfFrame endOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    IEnumerator senderCOR()
    {

        bool isConnected = false;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;

        // Wait for client to connect in another Thread 
        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            while (!stop)
            {
                // Wait for client connection
                client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();
                // We are connected
                clients.Add(client);

                isConnected = true;
                stream = client.GetStream();
            }
        });

        //Wait until client has connected
        while (!isConnected)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        LOG("Connected!");

        bool readyToGetFrame = true;

        byte[] frameBytesLength = new byte[SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT];

        while (!stop)
        {
            //Wait for End of frame
            yield return endOfFrame;

            //currentTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height), 0, 0);  
            //currentTexture.Apply();

            //NEW CODE TO TRY
            using (var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())     { 
                if(!image.IsAvailable)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }

                _OnImageAvailable(image.Width, image.Height, image.Y, image.Width * image.Height);
            }

            //currentTexture.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
            byte[] pngBytes = currentTexture.EncodeToPNG();
            //Fill total byte length to send. Result is stored in frameBytesLength
            byteLengthToFrameByteArray(pngBytes.Length, frameBytesLength);

            //Set readyToGetFrame false
            readyToGetFrame = false;

            Loom.RunAsync(() =>
            {
                //Send total byte count first
                stream.Write(frameBytesLength, 0, frameBytesLength.Length);
                LOG("Sent Image byte Length: " + frameBytesLength.Length);

                //Send the image bytes
                stream.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
                LOG("Sending Image byte array data : " + pngBytes.Length);

                //Sent. Set readyToGetFrame true
                readyToGetFrame = true;
            });

            //Wait until we are ready to get new frame(Until we are done sending data)
            while (!readyToGetFrame)
            {
                LOG("Waiting To get new frame");
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }


    void LOG(string messsage)
    {
        if (enableLog)
            Debug.Log(messsage);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        myImage.texture = webCam;
    }

    // stop everything
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (webCam != null && webCam.isPlaying)
        {
            webCam.Stop();
            stop = true;
        }

        if (listner != null)
        {
            listner.Stop();
        }

        foreach (TcpClient c in clients)
            c.Close();
    }

    private void _OnImageAvailable(int width, int height, IntPtr pixelBuffer, int bufferSize){

        currentTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
        byte[] bufferYUV = new byte[width * height * 3 / 2];
        bufferSize = width * height * 3 / 2;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, bufferYUV, 0, bufferSize);
        Color color = new Color();
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {

                float Yvalue = bufferYUV[y * width + x];
                float Uvalue = bufferYUV[(y / 2) * (width / 2) + x / 2 + (width * height)];
                float Vvalue = bufferYUV[(y / 2) * (width / 2) + x / 2 + (width * height) + (width * height) / 4];
                color.r = Yvalue + (float)(1.37705 * (Vvalue - 128.0f));
                color.g = Yvalue - (float)(0.698001 * (Vvalue - 128.0f)) - (float)(0.337633 * (Uvalue - 128.0f));
                color.b = Yvalue + (float)(1.732446 * (Uvalue - 128.0f));

                color.r /= 255.0f;
                color.g /= 255.0f;
                color.b /= 255.0f;

                if (color.r < 0.0f)
                    color.r = 0.0f;
                if (color.g < 0.0f)
                    color.g = 0.0f;
                if (color.b < 0.0f)
                    color.b = 0.0f;

                if (color.r > 1.0f)
                    color.r = 1.0f;
                if (color.g > 1.0f)
                    color.g = 1.0f;
                if (color.b > 1.0f)
                    color.b = 1.0f;

                color.a = 1.0f;
                currentTexture.SetPixel(width - 1 - x, y, color);
            }
        }


        currentTexture.Apply();
        //this.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = m_TextureRender;
    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
public class MySocketsClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage image;
    public bool enableLog = false;

    const int port = 8010;
    //public string IP = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
    public string IP = "xxx.xxx.x.x";
    TcpClient client;

    Texture2D tex;

    private bool stop = false;

    //This must be the-same with SEND_COUNT on the server
    const int SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT = 15;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        tex = new Texture2D(0, 0);
        client = new TcpClient();

        //Connect to server from another Thread
        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            LOGWARNING("Connecting to server...");
            // if on desktop
            //client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

            // if using the IPAD
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
            LOGWARNING("Connected!");

            imageReceiver();
        });
    }


    void imageReceiver()
    {
        Debug.Log("Here");
        //While loop in another Thread is fine so we don't block main Unity Thread
        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            while (!stop)
            {
                //Read Image Count
                int imageSize = readImageByteSize(SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT);
                LOGWARNING("Received Image byte Length: " + imageSize);

                //Read Image Bytes and Display it
                readFrameByteArray(imageSize);
            }
        });
    }


    //Converts the data size to byte array and put result to the fullBytes array
    void byteLengthToFrameByteArray(int byteLength, byte[] fullBytes)
    {
        //Clear old data
        Array.Clear(fullBytes, 0, fullBytes.Length);
        //Convert int to bytes
        byte[] bytesToSendCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteLength);
        //Copy result to fullBytes
        bytesToSendCount.CopyTo(fullBytes, 0);
    }

    //Converts the byte array to the data size and returns the result
    int frameByteArrayToByteLength(byte[] frameBytesLength)
    {
        int byteLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(frameBytesLength, 0);
        return byteLength;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////Read Image SIZE from Server///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private int readImageByteSize(int size)
    {
        bool disconnected = false;

        NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] imageBytesCount = new byte[size];
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytesCount, total, size - total);
            //Debug.LogFormat("Client recieved {0} bytes", total);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                disconnected = true;
                break;
            }
            total += read;
        } while (total != size);

        int byteLength;

        if (disconnected)
        {
            byteLength = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            byteLength = frameByteArrayToByteLength(imageBytesCount);
        }
        return byteLength;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////Read Image Data Byte Array from Server///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void readFrameByteArray(int size)
    {
        bool disconnected = false;

        NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[size];
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytes, total, size - total);
            //Debug.LogFormat("Client recieved {0} bytes", total);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                disconnected = true;
                break;
            }
            total += read;
        } while (total != size);

        bool readyToReadAgain = false;

        //Display Image
        if (!disconnected)
        {
            //Display Image on the main Thread
            Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                displayReceivedImage(imageBytes);
                readyToReadAgain = true;
            });
        }

        //Wait until old Image is displayed
        while (!readyToReadAgain)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }


    void displayReceivedImage(byte[] receivedImageBytes)
    {
        tex.LoadImage(receivedImageBytes);
        image.texture = tex;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }


    void LOG(string messsage)
    {
        if (enableLog)
            Debug.Log(messsage);
    }

    void LOGWARNING(string messsage)
    {
        if (enableLog)
            Debug.LogWarning(messsage);
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        LOGWARNING("OnApplicationQuit");
        stop = true;

        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help or thoughts on what might be causing the severe lag. Thanks!

Comment: it should be solved with render texture. there are some read-write traffic when you try to get the texture from ARCore.

Comment: it should be solved with render texture. there are some read-write traffic when you try to get the texture from ARCore.