# How to create indefinite Background Threads in a loop in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a loop which needs to create an unspecified and indefinite amount of Background threads.  The threads will then simply run to completion but some may need to be cancelled.

I originally planned to do this by declaring one backgroundWorker, adding it to a list, then newing the BackgroundWorker to begin the process again.  However because the List.Add method runs by reference to the passed in object I am thinking that when I new the original BackgroundWorker, the thread referenced by the List will be lost (or worse).

My second thought was simply assigning my newed value to a element in an array (array[i] = new BackgroundWorker()) but this does not lend itself to an indefinite amount of threads.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a good way to manage these individual threads? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An array element would still contain only a reference to your object so `your second thought == your first thought`. Note that Lists use arrays internally; they just resize themselves upon reaching the threshold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two comments - one micro, one macro.

First, it seems like the TPL will fit your stated goals.  Using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, you'll be able to spawn an arbitrary amount of operations which will run on background threads.  Further, using the overloads that take a CancellationToken, you cancel operations to as fine a degree as you might wish.  Note that a Task is not equivalent to a Thread - by default, Tasks run in ThreadPool threads (as do background workers, by the way).  It's entirely possible that your tasks will end up in a queue waiting for a pooled thread to become available.

Second, the bigger comment.

You claim that you will have an unspecified and indefinite number of work items.  That you would spawn a thread per item makes me a bit edgy - threads aren't cheap, and if you have a large number of work items you can starve your process by naively starting new threads.

Can you elaborate on what you need to do with these threads?  I don't know what constitutes a work item for your project, but it's entirely possible that a producer/consumer setup with a fixed number of threads would meet your parallelization needs.  .NET 4.0 makes it easy with the System.Collections.Concurrent classes.

**EDIT in response to comment**

The case of TCP connections is very nearly what I was thinking about when I wrote the second comment above.  In this case, you are considering a potentially infinite consumption of a limited OS resource, namely open sockets.  I hope that you will investigate non-blocking I/O.  [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx) documents asynchronous reading from sockets, and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) talks about the larger asynchronous programming model in .NET.

For scalable TCP serving, a good discussion already exists on SO: [peruse at your pleasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869744/how-to-write-a-scalable-tcp-ip-based-server).

Comment: Each thread will be a new TCP connection transfer coming in from peers. I plan on serializing transfers coming from individual peers, but my number of peers needs to be relatively infinite (one million is a little ridiculous, but I would much prefer it to be a very large number), which meant that I needed to potentially have infinite threads running.  I imagine if it ends up bogging down with lots of concurrent transfers then I would impose some sort of concurrent transfer maximum and thus limit my max concurrent threads.