# Out of memory exception when receiving large amounts of data on TCP connection

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, stream

I have an application that receives data from GPRS clients in the field on a TCP connection. From time to time the GPRS client devices loses connection and buffers the data, when the connection is restored all the buffered data is send to the TCP connection, cauing my application to throw a System.OutOfMemoryException.

I presume this is because the data received is bigger than my buffer size (which is set to int.MaxValue).

1. How do I prevent my application to run out of memory?
2. How do I make sure that I do not lose any of the incomming data?

Below is the code used to listen for, and  handle incomming data

```
public void Listen(string ip, int port)
{
    _logger.Debug("All.Tms.SensorDataServer : SensorDataListener : Listen");

    try
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            client.SendBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

            var thread = new Thread(() => ReadAndHandleIncommingData(client));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("TMS.Sensor.SensorDataServer : SensorDataListener : Error : ", ex);
    }  
}
```

and

```
private void ReadAndHandleIncommingData(TcpClient connection)
{
     try
     {
         var stream = connection.GetStream();
         var data = new byte[connection.ReceiveBufferSize];

         var bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(connection.ReceiveBufferSize));

         var sensorDataMapper = new SensorDataMapperProvider().Get(data);

         if (sensorDataMapper != null)
         {
             _sensorDataHandler.Handle(sensorDataMapper.Map(data));
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("TMS.Sensor.SensorDataServer : SensorDataListener : ReadAndHandleIncommingData : Error : ", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("All.Tms.SensorDataServer : SensorDataListener : ReadAndHandleIncommingData : Error : ", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### About buffers

`OutOfMemoryException`s are thrown when there is no **sequential memory** left.
In your case, that means `connection.ReceiveBufferSize` is too big to keep in memory in one piece. Not because *the data received is bigger than your buffer size*.

You can use a smaller, fixed buffer to get the received bytes, append it somewhere and use the same buffer to receive the rest of the data, until you have it all.

One thing to look out for is the collection you use to store the received data. You can't use `List<byte>` for example because it stores its elements in a single array under the hood which makes no difference than getting everything in one go - like you do now.

You can see [MemoryTributary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream), a stream implementation meant to replace `MemoryStream`. You can copy your stream to this one and keep it as a stream. This page also contains a lot of information that can help you understand the causes of the `OutOfMemoryException`s.

In addition, I wrote a buffer manager to provide fixed sized buffers a while ago. You can find that in Code Review, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/17804/17039).

### About threads

Creating a thread for *every single connection* is **brutal**. They cost you 1 MB each so you should either use `ThreadPool` or better, IOCP (via asynchronous methods of the `Socket` class).

You may want to look into these for common pitfalls and best practices about socket programming:

- [Stephen Cleary (the blog) | TCP/IP .NET Sockets FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html)
- [Stack Overflow | How to write a scalable Tcp/Ip based server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869744/704144)
- [Code Project | C# SocketAsyncEventArgs High Performance Socket Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)

Answer (score 2):

Use a fixed receive buffer, and parse data incrementally

Comment: Use async sockets using System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs

Comment: and yes, for each thread you need 1 MB for the stack. How many concurrent connections you have?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into all the suggestions. 1+